# Problema de conexion con mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

estoy tratando de conectarme a mongodb y lo hace pero tengo un problema, y es que cuando mando un log para que me muestre si la conexion fue exitosa, se ejecuta dos veces el mensaje no se si eso es normal o tengo problemas en el codigo.

```
package connection

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "time"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/readpref"
)

// Client es la instancia de la coneccion
var Client = Connection()

// Connection es la funcion que me permite conectarme a mongodb
func Connection() *mongo.Client {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))

    defer func() {
        if err = client.Disconnect(ctx); err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
    }()

    err = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Primary())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    log.Println("conexion exitosa a mongodb")

    return client
}
```

Comment: Tu código actual funciona y muestra una sola vez el mensaje: `conexion exitosa a mongodb`. ¿Seguro lo estás llamando una única vez?

Comment: si pero nose porque me muestra dos veces el mensaje

Comment: Se necesita más contexto para poder determinar el problema. Te sugiero que leas [mcve]. Tal como está escrito tu código (exceptuando tal vez algún detalle de implementación) funciona y sólo muestra por consola 1 vez el mensaje de conexión satisfactoria. Saludos